# Unexpected return message from mpirun: "alarm clock"

Tags: c, mpi

I have the simplest code "Hello world"

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf and BUFSIZ defined there */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit defined there */
#include <mpi.h>    /* all MPI-2 functions defined there */

int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
   int rank, size, length;
   char name[BUFSIZ];

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   MPI_Get_processor_name(name, &length);

   printf("%s: hello world from process %d of %d\n", name, rank, size);

   MPI_Finalize();

   exit(0);
}
```

I have compiled it

```
mpicc -o hello hello.c
```

and tried to run it with 4 processes

```
mpirun -np 4 hello
```

it returns;

```
chasan@ubuntu:~/MpiProgrammes$ mpicc -o hello Hello.c
chasan@ubuntu:~/MpiProgrammes$ mpirun -np 4 hello
Alarm clock
chasan@ubuntu:~/MpiProgrammes$
```

What could it be ?

Comment: Which platform and MPI implementation are you using, including versions?

Comment: Did you lamboot (start the lam mpi daemons) before mpirun-ing?  eg, lamboot; mpirun -np 4 hello; lamhalt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the command "mpd &"